# Origin of "map" in Computer Science

Tags: dictionary, associative-array, terminology, history

In computer science, there are two definitions of the word map. The first is as an associative array, a type of container that maps values of one type to values of another type. An example of this is the [STL map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/). The second definition is from functional programming, in which map is a function that takes a list and a function, applies the function to all elements of the list in order, and returns a list of results.

What are the origins of the different definitions of map? I'm guessing that the second definition might have come from the [mapcar function from McCarthy LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Control_structures), but I'm not sure if that was derived from another useful. The first definition makes intuitive sense to me, but I'm not sure where it came from.

Comment: Is there a computer terminology etymologist in the house?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both of these constructs define a map in the mathematical sense: a mapping of elements from one set to another.

Comment: To expound on this, the first definition describes a map, whereas the second definition describes the process of mapping.  Consider:  if you used the function map to map a list to a new list, and put the new and the old list side by side, you would have a map (associative array.)

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's the mathematical meaning of *[map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics))*, which is a pairing of elements from one set to another.